# Cocoapods Could Not Find Remote Branch to Clone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, cocoapods

I'm running into an issue outlined at https://github.com/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/issues/22. The Podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'BNGAPI'
```

This Podfile worked fine with the 0.33.1 version of cocoapods, but started failing with the 0.34.0.rc1 version of cocoa pods. The full stack trace from a `pod install --verbose` looks like:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:70:in `execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:9:in `execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:152:in `block in executable'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:65:in `block in clone'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:40:in `block in ui_sub_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:49:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:39:in `ui_sub_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:63:in `clone'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:29:in `download!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `block in download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:24:in `block in ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:49:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:23:in `ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.7.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:78:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:98:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:45:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:298:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:273:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:70:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:272:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:264:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:264:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:49:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:91:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.7.0/lib/claide/command.rb:271:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.34.0.rc1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried pointing my Podfile at a specific commit and branch, but I just keep getting the same error message. The tag in question is 2.0 and has been published to github at https://github.com/betfair/aping-ios-sdk/tree/tags/2.0. It's spec is available at https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/BNGAPI/2.0/BNGAPI.podspec.json.

Is there anything awry with my Podfile for pointing at the 2.0 version of BNGAPI?

FWIW, I'm using the 0.35.0 version of cocoapods with the ruby-2.0.0-p598 version of ruby.

Comment: Please show your Podfile

Comment: Good idea @GuillaumeAlgis - altered the question to put the Podfile inline.